# Is it possible to expose nodes localhost to my host?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, npm, ddev

I am currently working on an Ionic based project. due to the fact I don't want to install node.js locally I tried DDEV, even it is supposed to be a PHP development environment.

However, when serving my application via `ionic serve -l` the frontend of my app is built and should be accessible (within the container) on `http://localhost:8200`. Well, I have to expose this port to my host I guess.

To do so I already tried a few configurations, but nothing worked out. For example:

1. I configured the nginx-site-conf for listening on port 8200. A weak try, I know but I had to try.
2. Furthermore I created a `docker-compose.override.yaml` and added the port 8200 to be exposed to my host. Didn't work out well.

Has anyone an idea or is DDEV just not the right tool for that job?

Comment: Why don’t you want to install node locally?  (It’s usually a single `apt-get install` or `brew install` command; usually everything else you need winds up in the per-package `node_modules` tree.)

Comment: 1. I'm the type of person who wants to keep his host clean.
2. Why does DDEV ship Node.js with the container when you can't use it efficiently.

Of course I can install Node.js locally, I will probably have to do it as part of my project, because I simply don't have the time.  But there has to be an efficient way, I'm just not trained enough to figure it out by myself.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to do a docker-compose.extraport.yaml (name of the file is arbitrary) that exposes that port to the host.

I tried this .ddev/docker-compose.extraport.yaml and it worked fine. I just tested it with `nc -l -p 8200` inside the container, and `telnet localhost 8200` on the host.

```html
version: '3.6'

services:
  web:
    ports:
    - published: 8200
      target: 8200
```

Details about adding extra docker-compose files are at https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/extend/additional-services/ and https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/extend/custom-compose-files/ - those are mostly aimed at people creating a completely new service, but it all works the same for overriding as here.